# SP2010 Page Viewer [web part] turns grey when selecting links embedded in a pdf?

Tags: navigation, page-viewer-web-part

I have a pdf with many embedded links, which I have placed in a typical SP2010 Page Viewer web part.

Any/all embedded links to a *.txt file, or another sites library directory listing, open in the Page Viewer window fine....and I can select 'Back' to navigate to go back to my pdf. works great.

My issue, is that when users select any link to a .doc/.ppt, the Page Viewer window turns GREY, and the doc/ppt opens fine in it's own Office window.

So the links work in all cases, it just with the docs/ppts, my Page Viewer window is stuck in GREY and I/users must re-navigate, to re-situate themselves on the sub-site/page viewer to access the pdf and thus any subsequent selection of embedded links...

Have I made myself crystal clear ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been informed that it a direct result of our [very large] organization, not having purchased the requisite Office 'web parts'; and thus the page viewer turns grey.

The other way to achieve the links within a graphic/image, is to create url 'hotspots' in an image, using SP Designer, Visio, or handralically HTML it from scratch. Visio here we go !